# Complex search query from 2 documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to `Elasticsearch` and I need to execute a complex query, but I need some help.

Here is my use case:

I would like to recommend a new place to each of my users everyday.
However:

- The place must be opened this week day
- The chosen place must be near of the user (closer places have higher score)
- The place should not be one of the last 10 places a user have already been/suggested (if a place has already been visited by a user in his last 10 visits, this place should have a lower score)

My first guess is to have 2 documents types as follow:

**user_history**

- `user_id`
- `place_id`
- `date`

**place**

- `place_id`
- `opening_days` (array with week days the place opens)
- `location` geo position of the place

Given a user with position `[lat, lon]` and id `user_1`, what could be the search query to execute to retrieve X places sorted by score? (better score is near of user and not in the 10 last places a user have already been).

This query seems to be a basic but I can't figure out how to "mix" data from `user_history` and from `place` to get `place`s I want.

But that's not all!

With this query, if I want to attribute to each user a place I need 3 steps:

- retrieve all users (with their position)
- for each user, search for the best place
- once I have this place, add it to the `user_history`

This seems very time consuming task. Is it possible to simplify it with less `Elasticsearch` queries?

For instance, having something like this:

- retrieving for each user his best place (with 1 query, search for all users and find them the best place)
- add the place to the history

Or event better:

- retrieving for each user his best place and add it to the history (with 1 query, perform all the 3 tasks above)

I don't know if it's possible to create queries that complex. That's why I need your help to tell me if it's possible and how it could be accomplished.

Comment: looks a bit complex, especially the part retrieve all users (doesn't look like Elastic use case at all), probably it's better to retrieve them from datasource?

Comment: @Mysterion you mean retrieving my users from a relational DB and then finding best place from ES? Wouldn't it be too time consuming with a lot of users?

Comment: ES is not a database for doing full scans, it's optimized to retrieve documents, based on some criteria, so, of course under some circumstances, ES will be faster than DB, but in general it's not Elastic job and it will hurt you, sooner, or later

Comment: Ok, I understand, but we do agree that ES is a good choice for the "search for best place" task right?

Comment: Can't you performe two queries? First one to retrieve the last visited placed in a range of time, the second to retrieve recommendations with a must_not clause holding the places ids.

Comment: @mayid Yes I could do that, but I wanted to know if there was a way to optimize this by performing only one query